# How to suppress the 'Invalid class attribute name "id"' pylint warning for Django models?

Tags: python, django, pylint

The default primary key column in Django models is named `id`, which is not a valid class attribute name according to `pylint`. How can I suppress the `'Invalid class attribute name "id"'` pylint warning for Django model classes (or for the whole project) ?

Comment: Do you really need to define the `id` field? Django will automatically give your models a primary key, so you don't need to define the id field unless you want something like a UUID field for the primary key.

Comment: @Alasdair: Yes, that's exactly the case. And I want them to be consistent with the rest..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# pylint: disable=C0103
```

Put the line in the Models files and it will mute the warnings and if you it at the end of a line of code just disable this message for that line.

Comment: You could also add it to the `good-names` list in `.pylintrc`